# Validate Form in Zend Framework 2 with subforms

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

I have a form with a subform. My question is how to validate that? I don't have any idea how to validate this form with subforms. This is the code:

```
$this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'manual',
    'attributes' => array(
        'type'  => 'hidden',
        'value'=>'1',
    ),
));
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'id',
    'attributes' => array(
        'type'  => 'hidden',
    ),
));

$subForm = new \Zend\Form\Form();
$subForm->setName('name');
$subForm->add( array(
    'name' => 'ca',
    'type' => 'text',
));
$subForm->add( array(
    'name' => 'en',
    'type' => 'text',
));
$subForm->add( array(
    'name' => 'es',
    'type' => 'text',
));
$this->add($subForm);
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'acronym',
    'attributes' => array(
        'type'  => 'text',
        'placeholder' => 'acronym',
        'class' => 'docnet-form-acronym-entity',
    ),
));
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'submit',
    'attributes' => array(
        'type'  => 'submit',
        'class' => 'btn',
        'value' => 'add',
        'id' => 'submitbutton',
    ),
));
```

I made this form because I had an array to the element name. To list it it works but now I want to edit and I can't get validated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a `Zend\Form\Fieldset` instead of a sub form. It makes the validation a lot easier. ZF2 actually has a useful example in the [docs on collections](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html).